Find customers where the billing date is in order
I am trying to get below query resolve in power query but after trying 2-3 times it will not resolved yet, hope can someone help me in this, in below table i m trying to get answer in yes/no for analyzing sequential billing happened to a customer for his single order.
Customer    Customer Name   Invoice No  Date    Sales Order Sales Quantity  Sales No. of Boxes
8512673 ABC Co. 7330538466  03/07/2024  5226538466  10  1
8512673 ABC Co. 7330540349  06/07/2024  5226540349  30  3
8512673 ABC Co. 7330541074  08/07/2024  5226541074  8   1
8512673 ABC Co. 7330542083  09/07/2024  5226541074  20  2
8512673 ABC Co. 7330542981  10/07/2024  5226541074  30  3
8512673 ABC Co. 7330543221  10/07/2024  5226543221  110 11
8512673 ABC Co. 7330544139  11/07/2024  5226544139  20  2
8512673 ABC Co. 7330545028  12/07/2024  5226544139  8   2
8512673 ABC Co. 7330545054  12/07/2024  5226545054  60  5
8512673 ABC Co. 7330546880  15/07/2024  5226546880  641.8   38
8512682 XYZ Co. 7330539099  04/07/2024  5226539099  9.6 2
8512682 XYZ Co. 7330539105  04/07/2024  5226539099  60  5
8512682 XYZ Co. 7330544844  12/07/2024  5226544844  60  5
8512682 XYZ Co. 7330556070  25/07/2024  5226556070  66  10

need answer in a new column with Yes/No data with analyzing above table query...
Here is answer as Example


@horseyride- pls chk
